# Saddle point method used to calculate the inverse Fourier transform

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, estimation, integral, saddlepoint-approximation

Here I want to find the asymptotic behavior of the following integral
$$f(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-ikx)*\exp(t(1-\exp(-|k|^\beta)))dk,~~~~~~~Eq~1$$
where $x$ goes to infinity.

So I try to use the saddle point approximation to find the asymptotic behavior of the above formula.
According to the saddle point method, we should first find the saddle point
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k} (-ikx+t(1-\exp(-|k|^\beta))=0~~~~~~~~~Eq. 2$$.
Using the Mathematica, the solution of Eq.~(2) is
$$k_0=\left(-\frac{(\beta -1) W\left(-\frac{\beta  \left(-\frac{i x}{\beta  t}\right)^{\frac{\beta }{\beta -1}}}{\beta -1}\right)}{\beta }\right)^{1/\beta }$$
Here $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Notice that $k_0$ is a complex number instead of a real number. According to [enter link description here](https://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/%7Edmarendu/MOMP/lecture05.pdf), I should find the angle $\theta$; see the circles in the figure
[image]

Clearly, $\theta$ is not fixed.

My problems:  1) In principle, the saddle point approximation is valid here?

```
            2)  Are there other methods to calculate the behavior of the large $x$ for Eq.~1?
```